# How can I get my Lexical analyzer program to print out more than just seperators?

Tags: c, lexical-analysis

Im writing a Lexical analyzer to read from a file and describe the text as either identifiers, keywords, separators, or operators. For some reason I am only able to output the separators, unless I delete or comment out the while loop with the print statement for the separators. When I delete that, the program prints out everything else correctly, skipping over the separators.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int isKeyword(char buffer[]){
    char keywords[32][10] = {"auto","break","case","char","const","continue","default",
                            "do","double","Else","enum","Function","Float","for","goto",
                            "If","Integer","long","register","Return","short","signed",
                            "sizeof","static","struct","switch","typedef","union",
                            "DOWhile","void","Write","while"};
    int i, flag = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 32; ++i){
        if(strcmp(keywords[i], buffer) == 0){
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

     int k, flag2 = 0;

    for (k = 0; k<32; ++k){
        if(strcmp(keywords[i], buffer) == 0){
        flag2 = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    return flag;


    return flag2;
}

int main(){
    char ch, buffer2[15], operators[] = "+-*/%=";

    char ch2, buffer[15], seperators[] = "{}(),;";
    FILE *fp;

    int i,k,j=0;

    fp = fopen("input.txt","r");

    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("error while opening the file\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
           for(i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
               if(ch == operators[i])
                   printf("%c is operator\n", ch);

    while((ch2 = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
      for(k = 0; k < 6; ++k){
           if(ch2 == seperators[k])
           printf("%c is seperator\n", ch2);
        }
           }

           if(isalnum(ch)){
               buffer[j++] = ch;
           }
           else if((ch == ' ' || ch == '\n') && (j != 0)){
                   buffer[j] = '\0';
                   j = 0;

                   if(isKeyword(buffer) == 1)
                       printf("%s is keyword\n", buffer);
                   else
                       printf("%s is indentifier\n", buffer);
           }

    }
 }   
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem seems to be the second while loop containing the separator instructions, but I cant seem to figure out how to print that along with everything else.

Comment: Is this homework? I wouldn't be unwilling to answer certain questions about it if it were, but which questions I would be willing to answer would depend on the answer to that question...

Comment: You seem to have two `return` statements in your function? Also, I spotted to many `32`s around. Why not define a constant, say `#define NUMKW 32` and use it instead? Easier to manage

Comment: @TagoreSmith Yes it is

Comment: OK- well I have to be honest... this code is hard to follow, because it doesn't make a lot of sense. But let's start with a nudge: can the line that reads 'return flag2;' ever be reached?

Comment: Also- can you look at the two loops involved and tell me how they are similar and how they differ (hint: how they index into 'keywords'?)

Comment: This does a lot of work it shouldn't have to do; [re2c](https://re2c.org/) would definitely help. Even [gperf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/).

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help.There is no reason to create an additional char ch, or the buffer, when creating the separators. Just add it onto the end of the previous line. I just split it with a comma.This will clean your code up and allow you to keep the separators with the rest of the while loop code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define KEY 32
#define BUFFER_SIZE 15

int isKeyword(char buffer[])
{
    char keywords[KEY][10] = { "auto","break","case","char","const","continue","default", "do","double","else","enum","extern","float","for","goto",
    "if","int","long","register","return","short","signed", "sizeof","static","struct","switch","typedef","union", "unsigned","void","volatile","while"};

    int i, flag = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < KEY; ++i)
    {
        if (strcmp(keywords[i], buffer) == 0)
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}

int main()
{
    char ch, buffer[BUFFER_SIZE], operators[] = "+-*/%=", separators[] = "(){}[]<>,";
    FILE *fp;
    int i, j = 0;
    fp = fopen("Text.txt", "r");

    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {

        for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
        {
            if (ch == operators[i])
            {
                printf(" OPERATOR:     %c \n", ch);
            }
            else if (ch == separators[i])
                printf(" SEPARATOR:    %c \n", ch);
        }

        if (isalnum(ch))
        {
            buffer[j++] = ch;
        }
        else if ((ch == ' ' || ch == '\n') && (j != 0))
        {
            buffer[j] = '\0';
            j = 0;
            {
                if (isKeyword(buffer) == 1)
                    printf(" KEYWORD:      %s \n", buffer);
                else
                    printf(" IDENTIFIER:   %s \n", buffer);
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

[image]